# Sorting a list of names in python

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

Can anyone have a look at this code please? I am trying to sort a list of names. But somehow only the 'Sorted by last name' works and the other one would have a memory error. Why?

```
def merge(left, right, compare):
    """Assumes left and right are sorted lists and compare defines an ordering
         on the elements.
       Returns a new sorted (by compare) list containing the same elements as
         (left + right) would contain."""
    result= []
    i, j = 0,0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if compare(left[i], right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
    return result

import operator

def mergeSort(L, compare=operator.lt):
    """Assumes L is a list, compare defines an ordering on elements of L
       Returns a new sorted list containing the same elemetns as L"""
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L)//2
        left = mergeSort(L[:middle],compare)
        right = mergeSort(L[middle:],compare)
        return merge(left, right, compare)

def lastNameFirstName(name1, name2):
    import string
    name1 = string.split(name1, ' ')
    name2 = string.split(name2, ' ')
    if name1[1] != name2[1]:
        return name1[1] < name2[1]
    else: #last names are the same, sort by first names
        return name1[0] < name2[0]

def firstNameLastName(name1, name2):
    import string
    name1 = string.split(name1, ' ')
    name2 = string.split(name2, ' ')
    if name1[0] != name2[0]:
        return name1[0] < name2[0]
    else: #first names the same, sort by last name
        return name1[1] < name2[1]

L = ['Chris Terman', 'Tom Brady', 'Eric Grimson', 'Gisele Bundchen']
newL = mergeSort(L, lastNameFirstName)
print 'Sorted by last name =', newL
newL = mergeSort(L, firstNameLastName)
print 'Sorted by first name =', newL
```

The 'Sorted by last name' one works fine but the next one does not work.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to be using the `string` module here. `string.split(name1, ' ')` should be written `name1.split(' ')`.

Comment: Also, please post the actual error and the traceback.

Comment: I guess you're missing `j += 1` near the end of `merge`

Comment: "Debug my code" is not a valid question. Give us a stripped-down version of your code, the smallest thing that reproduces the problem. Explain exactly what the problem is. Include the actual error and traceback if there's an error, or the different between the expected and actual output if there isn't. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did miss j += 1 in the merge function...Should have examined it more carefully before posting it here.

Comment: This code works fine now. But when I separate this code into two files(the first one contains merge and `mergeSort` functions, the second one contains the rest of the code), and import the `mergeSort` function in the second file, it would produce a `memoryError`. However, when I put all the code in one file it works fine. Why?

Comment: @HakunaMatata: Just post a new question and provide easy steps for us to reproduce the problem. Good luck!

Comment: @georg: Thanks. I have got it working now. However, I did not really change anything. It is strange that the same files and code did not work properly yesterday( `memoryError`), but worked absolutely fine today!!?? Any explanations?

Comment: @HakunaMatata: sun activity?? Seriously, no idea. If you get it reproducable, feel free to post a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with simple sorted we can acheive this

```
L = ['Chris Terman', 'Tom Brady', 'Eric Grimson', 'Gisele Bundchen']

print sorted(L,key=lambda x:x.split()[-1]) # sorted by last name
['Tom Brady', 'Gisele Bundchen', 'Eric Grimson', 'Chris Terman']

print sorted(L)# sorted first name
['Chris Terman', 'Eric Grimson', 'Gisele Bundchen', 'Tom Brady']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I know sorted can achieve this. I was just trying to practice this merge sort algorithm. It turned out I missed j+=1 at the end of the merge function.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this as a controlled assessment in school. Here is my piece of name sorting code:

```
with open("sorting.txt", 'w') as myfile:
myfile.write("Ryan\nJames\nOliver\nBen\nYazmin")
myfile.close()

with open("sorting.txt", 'r') as myfile:
lineList = myfile.readlines()     #Reads the lines within the file.
lineList.sort()     # Sorts the lines by the first letter in each line.
print('The input in alphabetical order below :')
for names in  lineList:
    print(names)
```

Follow this link: [Online Python Interpretor](http://repl.it/languages/Python/) to try out the code, or copy it and use it on your computer. The link is safe!